# Perfect Forward Secrecy in MTI/A0

Tags: keys, forward-secrecy

Would the property of perfect forward secrecy still be achieved in MTI/A0 for a session key that was established between C and D when one LL-key aD is revealed so that both LL-keys aC and aD are revealed?

Comment: I encourage you to define the terminology you use (e.g., MTI/A0, LL-key), as I'm not familiar to them.  Also, if you have a link to the paper(s) that introduce this scheme, I encourage you to post them.  This might increase the chances that you get a good answer.

Comment: Did anyone find an answer to this?